# Kernel and scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I need to prove that $k(x,y)=f(x)f(y),\ f: \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous function and $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$, is a Mercer kernel, i.e. for any $x_1,...x_n \in \mathbb R^d$ and any $c_1,...c_n\in \mathbb R,\, $ the inequality holds $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n c_ic_jk(x_i, x_j) \geq 0,$$
whereby $k:\mathbb R^d$x $ \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$ represents the kernel.

In the case $f$ is linear, we could define the scalar product $<x_i,x_j>:=f(x_i)f(x_j).$ Given that the scalar product is a positive definite symmetric bilinear form, the inequality will hold. I am having difficulty in considering non linear continuous functions $f$.

Can somebody provide an idea or a solution proposal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_i\sum_j c_ic_jk(x_i,x_j)=\sum_i\sum_j c_ic_j f(x_i)f(x_j)=(\sum_i c_i f(x_i))(\sum_j c_j f(x_j))=(\sum_k c_k f(x_k))^2$.